# How do I use VBOs to render a texture in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I am using the Lightweight Java Game Library to attempt to make a BrickBreaker-type game. I have made an extremely simple 16x16 png texture for the brick - I know how to render the texture using immediate mode, but how can I do it with Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs), or even just vertex arrays? Please give me all code, from generating the handles and the data to the rendering. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Nobody's going to write your code for you, but you may find some inspiration here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples

Comment: just read some more tutorials :)

Answer (score 0):

You pass texture coordinates in the same way that you pass vertex coordinates. So instead of

```
glVertexPointer
```

you write

```
glTexCoordPointer
```